# error: ‘IOV_MAX’ undeclared (first use in this function)

Tags: c++, c, gcc

I'm trying to install [memcached-1.2.8-repcached-2.2.1](http://sourceforge.net/projects/repcached/files/latest/download?source=files)

I have the following error after running `make`:

```
$ make  all-recursive 
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/local/src/pro/memcached-1.2.8-repcached-2.2.1'     
Making all in doc
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/local/src/pro/memcached-1.2.8-repcached-2.2.1/doc'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/pro/memcached-1.2.8-repcached-2.2.1/doc'
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/local/src/pro/memcached-1.2.8-repcached-2.2.1'
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -DNDEBUG   -g -O2 -MT memcached-memcached.o -MD -MP -MF 
.d eps/memcached-memcached.Tpo -c -o memcached-memcached.o `test -f 'memcached.c' || echo './'`memcached.c
memcached.c: In function ‘add_iov’:
memcached.c:697: error: ‘IOV_MAX’ undeclared (first use in this function)
memcached.c:697: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
memcached.c:697: error: for each function it appears in.)
make[2]: *** [memcached-memcached.o] Error 1     
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/pro/memcached-1.2.8-repcached-2.2.1'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/pro/memcached-1.2.8-repcached-2.2.1'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

OS : Centos5.7 64bit

gcc-4.1.2-51.el5

gcc-c++-4.1.2-51.el5

libgcc-4.1.2-51.el5

Is there any thing wrong with IOV_MAX in gcc, file headers ...etc .?

Comment: Wrong with it?  I don't know about that, but it appears it's not defined in your environment as is.

Comment: @CarlNorum Does it need to be declared in specific header file .? , If yes Could  you please provide me with the file name or a link to download this file to /usr/include

Comment: [`#include limits.h`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/basedefs/sys/uio.h.html) should pull in `IOV_MAX`.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz /usr/include/limits.h doesn't include any IOV `grep IOV /usr/include/limits.h` didn't grep any thing.

Comment: @RamyAllam You can't use `grep` to tell what a header file does because header files include other header files.

Comment: For future reference, POSIX specifies that `IOV_MAX` is defined in `<limits.h>` (see [the spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/limits.h.html#tag_13_24)).  Of course, implementations are free to define it in a different header which is included by `<limits.h>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should

yum remove libevent2-devel

yum install libevent libevent-devel

Answer (score 1):

This indicates there is a flaw in the include files or maybe the include path or environment.

It is straightforward how it should have been defined:

`memcached.c` line 33 should define `__need_IOV_MAX`
`memcached.c` line 42 includes `stdio.h`
`stdio.h` (on my system anyway) line 161 includes `bits/stdio_lim.h`
The last lines of `stdio_lim.h` (lines 42-43) should define it:

```
#if defined __need_IOV_MAX && !defined IOV_MAX
# define IOV_MAX 1024
#endif
```

I tried building memcached, but there is something messed up with how it depends on libevent.  This is the last few lines from `configure` on Fedora 15:

```
...
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking for libevent directory... configure: error: libevent is required.
You can get it from http://www.monkey.org/~provos/libevent/

      If it's already installed, specify its path using --with-libevent=/dir/

[wally@lenovotower memcached-1.2.8-repcached-2.2.1]$ rpm -q libevent
libevent-2.0.10-2.fc15.i686
[wally@lenovotower memcached-1.2.8-repcached-2.2.1]$
```

But there is no `event.h` anywhere in `/usr/...`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the same situation compiling on Ubuntu 12.10 (and possibly other versions), you need to install the libevent1-dev package.